# How does a Keycloak client validate a token

Tags: keycloak

I would like to know how does a Keycloak client validate the token, other than checking the signature.
I mean if a user has issued a logout request to the OID '/logout' endpoint, the token signature verification would still pass, so if the token has been invalidated by a logout, the client has to go to the KC server. So my question is, does the client go to Keycloak to check that the token is still valid, for every request that my app receives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OIDC normally the token is not actively checked by sending it to the keycloak server everytime. Instead the token is only checked locally (by signature verfication with the servers public key).

So you are right, a logout is not immediately recognized by a client.

Because of that you often have a flow where you distinguish between a `refresh` and `access` token. The `access_token` has a really short lifetime (<= 5 minutes), is used to authenticate the user and checked via signature validation.
When the `access_token` is not valid anymore the client need to use the `refresh_token` to actively obtain a new `access_token` from keycloak. In this step keycloak will check if the user is still logged-in before issuing the new token.

Because of that the `refresh_token` can have a much longer lifetime and it's not always necessary for the user to enter his credentials again.

Comment: thank you! one last question, since we're using OIDC and jwks we dont need to use the public key to verify the jwt on the server side, right?

Comment: That's correct - in this case you use directly the right `JWK` from the `JWKS` to validate the issued `JWT`

Comment: The reason I posted this question is because of this https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013005.html
which states that 'bearer-only' clients do verification online, so that inturn implies that other client types, like 'confidential' dont do the same.